# How do I rename fasta headers?

Tags: fasta

I am trying to use the [seqkit replace](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#replace) command to replace chromosome names in the format `chr_I, chr_II, ...` to `I, II, ...`. I am using the following command:

```
seqkit replace -p "(.)" --replacement "{kv}" --kv-file keyValues.txt mySequence.fasta
```

My `keyValues.txt` file contains the following:

```
chr_I   I
chr_II  II
...
```

The two columns are separated by a tabulation.

I get the following output:

```
[INFO] read key-value file: keyValues.txt
[INFO] 6 pairs of key-value loaded
[ERRO] pattern "(.)" matches multiple targets in "chr_I", this will cause chaos
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I chose the `(.)` pattern to match the whole header but it seems to be wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

#### Update

All the headers are shown below:

```
grep '>' mySequence.fasta
>chr_I
>chr_II
>chr_III
>chr_IV
>chr_V
>chr_X
```

Comment: Show some of the headers, the pattern argument is probably not suitable. I am guessing that you'll get headers with duplicate names now (which `will cause chaos`).

Comment: I have written all the header names in my question.

Comment: There are 4 matches to your pattern "chr_I"

Comment: Oh, so the key is a regular expression? I tried putting a dollar at the end of the key names, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use `sed` instead?

```
sed -e 's/chr_I/I/' -e 's/chr_V/V/' -e 's/chr_X/X/' mySequence.fasta > mySeq.fasta
```

Or even simpler:

```
sed 's/chr_//' mySequence.fasta > mySeq.fasta
```

Comment: Worked. I just don't know `sed`. I need to learn it.

Comment: Great! It works a bit like `grep` (which you know how to use), but then with replacement function.

Comment: I would suggest using `sed 's/^chr_//'` instead. Anchoring the pattern to the beginning of the line should speed things up for large files. Otherwise, `sed` will have to scan the entire length of each line in case there's a match.

Comment: @terdon, good point. But does it work with fasta? Remember the `>` at the beginning of the header.

Comment: @b.nota Duh! I should learn to read :) Indeed, `sed 's/^>chr_/>/` would be better.

Comment: Minor correction for the last: `sed 's/^>chr_/>/'` ( in order to keep the `>`)

Answer (score 2):

I like using `awk` when there's any kind of lookup involved: something like

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
    hash[">"$1]=$2;
    next;
}

if ($1 ~ /^>/) {
    print ">"hash[$1];
} else {
    print $1;
}' keyValues.txt mySequence.fasta
```

Basically the `FNR==NR` check tells awk to work only on the first file (useful primer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-is-nr-fnr-in-awk)), `keyValues.txt` and create an association for each key (eg. `chr_I`) with its value (eg. `I`). The rest of the code after the `next` works only on `mySequence.fasta`, printing out the lookup value only if the line is a fasta header, as checked by the `$1 ~ /^>/` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to sed: `cat test | tr -d "chr_"`

The pipe is to output the file, while the `tr` command is to translate and change the file

Comment: The use of the `cat` command is completely redundant here (and imposes a runtime overhead). Just do `tr -d 'chr_' < test`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the pattern `.` matches a single character. To match the whole header, use `.*`:

```sh
seqkit replace -p "(.*)" --replacement "{kv}" --kv-file keyValues.txt mySequence.fasta
```

Alternatively as pointed out by others you may not really need `keyValues.txt` here as you're just removing the `chr_` prefix:

```sh
seqkit replace -p "chr_(.*)" --replacement '$1' mySequence.fasta
```

(Don't forget the single quotes for `$1` else the shell will expand it)